# Table cells width - last one the longest, previous equal but as narrow as possible

Tags: sass, html-table

I don't even know how to start with the problem. I've got the table with a few columns (generated automatically). Let's say there are 5 columns. First I would have to take the first 4 columns, calculate auto width for them, take the longest one and set that width to all 4 of them - so that the first 4 columns have equal width of the widest one but are as narrow as only content allow. The last 5th column then has to fill the rest of the table. Is that possible to achieve that without js with scss only?